# Mejorar un if condicional

Tags: c#

Quisiera mejorar este código, estoy creando un juego tres en raya y este es un ejemplo para determinar ganador en la primera fila.

Me gustaría reducirlo pero que funcione igual.

Este es el código:

```
if (((tablero[0] == tablero[3])&& (tablero[0] == tablero[6])&& (tablero[0] != 0))
                    || ((tablero[0] == tablero[6]) && (tablero[0] == tablero[3]) && (tablero[0] != 0))
                    || ((tablero[6] == tablero[3])&&(tablero[6]== tablero[0])&&(tablero[6]!=0))
                    || ((tablero[6] == tablero[0]) && (tablero[6] == tablero[3]) && (tablero[6] != 0))
                    || ((tablero[3] == tablero[0]) && (tablero[3] == tablero[6]) && (tablero[3] != 0))
                    || ((tablero[3] == tablero[6]) && (tablero[3] == tablero[0]) && (tablero[3] != 0)))
                    hay3enRaya = true;
```

La ubicaciones son así: `0 3 6` - eso representa la primera fila de la matriz de 3x3.

Comment: Hola, no se si estás familiarizado con la instrucción [`switch`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/switch). Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: mas o menos pero no sé de que forma adaptarlo al switch

Comment: Encontré esta forma con solución minimax y recursividad. La primer versión es semejante a tu solución. http://www.jlabstudio.com/webgl/2013/09/tutorial-de-algoritmos-en-javascript-minimax-tres-en-raya/

Comment: excelente, es casi identico

Answer (score 2):

Teniendo en cuenta un tablero con estas posiciones y asumiendo que cada casilla puede tomar el valor de `0` para *vacío*, `1` para **`x`** y `2` para **`o`** (deducido de tu código):

```
[0][1][2]      [x][ ][o]      [1][0][2]
[3][4][5]  ->  [o][x][ ]  ->  [2][1][0]
[6][7][8]      [x][ ][o]      [1][0][2]
```

Como se sabe un tablero de tres en raya tiene 8 posibles soluciones para ganar:

- 3 soluciones verticales
- 3 horizontales y
- 2 diagonales

Podrías implementar este algoritmo, nada complejo y fácil de entender:

```
//soluciones horizontales
validar(0,1,2);
validar(3,4,5);
validar(6,7,8);

//soluciones verticales
validar(0,3,6);
validar(1,4,7);
validar(2,5,8);

//soluciones diagonales
validar(0,4,8);
validar(2,4,6);

public void validar(int a, int b, int c){
    //validas si no están vacíos
    if(tablero[a] != 0 && tablero[b] != 0 && tablero[c] != 0)
        // validas si son iguales
        if(tablero[a] == tablero[b] && tablero[b] == tablero[c])
                hay3enRaya = true;
}

Console.WriteLine(hay3enRaya);
```

---

*Hay maneras más óptimas de implementar el algoritmo de validación para un tres en raya, sobretodo usando recursividad, pero éso es más aplicable si te interesa rápidez y rendimiento en tu solución.*

Comment: excelente lo probaré

Comment: vale, si te funciono avisanos :)